# Why does C print different values than what PHP prints?

Tags: php, c

This is a complete noob question.

So here is my code in C,

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int I, X=4;
    double I0;
    double COEFF1[7];
    double COEFF2[9];
    /*Coefficient 1 I0*/
    COEFF1[0]=0.0045813;
    COEFF1[1]=0.0360768;
    COEFF1[2]=0.2659732;
    COEFF1[3]=1.2067492;
    COEFF1[4]=3.0899424;
    COEFF1[5]=3.5156229;
    COEFF1[6]=1.0000000;
    /*Coefficient 2 I0*/
    COEFF2[0]=0.00392377;
    COEFF2[1]=-0.01647633;
    COEFF2[2]=0.02635537;
    COEFF2[3]=-0.02057706;
    COEFF2[4]=0.00916281;
    COEFF2[5]=-0.00157565;
    COEFF2[6]=0.00225319;
    COEFF2[7]=0.01328592;
    COEFF2[8]=0.39894228;

    if(X>=3.75)
    {
        I0=COEFF2[0];
        for(I=1;I<9;I++)
        {
            I0=(3.75/X)*I0+COEFF2[I];
            printf("%i\n", I0);
        }
        //return I0/(sqrt(X)*exp(-X));
    }
    else
    {
        I0=COEFF1[0];
        for(I=1;I<7;I++)
        {
            I0=I0*(X/3.75)*(X/3.75)+COEFF1[I];
        }
        //return I0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And with little housekeeping, this is my translated code in PHP,

```
<?php
    $coeff1 =array();
    $coeff2 =array();
    /*Coefficient 1 $i0*/
    $coeff1[0]=0.0045813;
    $coeff1[1]=0.0360768;
    $coeff1[2]=0.2659732;
    $coeff1[3]=1.2067492;
    $coeff1[4]=3.0899424;
    $coeff1[5]=3.5156229;
    $coeff1[6]=1.0000000;
    /*Coefficient 2 $i0*/
    $coeff2[0]=0.00392377;
    $coeff2[1]=-0.01647633;
    $coeff2[2]=0.02635537;
    $coeff2[3]=-0.02057706;
    $coeff2[4]=0.00916281;
    $coeff2[5]=-0.00157565;
    $coeff2[6]=0.00225319;
    $coeff2[7]=0.01328592;
    $coeff2[8]=0.39894228;

    $x = 4;

    if($x>=3.75)
    {
        $i0=$coeff2[0];
        for($i=1;$i<9;$i++)
        {
            $i0=(3.75/$x)*$i0+$coeff2[$i];
            printf($i0."<br />");
        }
        //return $i0/(sqrt($x)*exp(-$x));
    }
    else
    {
        $i0=$coeff1[0];
        for($i=1;$i<7;$i++)
        {
            $i0=$i0*($x/3.75)*($x/3.75)+$coeff1[$i];
        }
        //return $i0;
    }
?>
```

But why won't they generate the same result?
http://imageshack.com/a/img59/3402/98ak.jpg

Please help. I'm stuck.

Comment: Clearly they are printing out the data using different types - one set are integers and one set are reals.  Which do you want?

Comment: If you're translating to PHP for comparison at very least use the equivalent format string in the PHP version something like `printf("%f\n", $i0);` and `printf("%f\n", I0);` in the C version

Comment: I'd like PHP to print the same results like what C prints

Answer (score 4):

`%i` is the format specifier for `int`; `I0` has type `double` but `printf` is being told to interpret it as `int`.  You should use `%f` for doubles instead:

```
printf("%f\n", I0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this bit might be useful too.

The difference in the output of the two programs can be attributed indeed to the line

```
printf("%i\n", I0);
```

in your C program where `I0` is interpreted as an integer but its bit pattern was stored as a `double` type which uses different logic for organizing the bits (and in the standard variation also uses a different number of bits). What the `printf` function does is that it just takes whatever that bit pattern was (in the length of an integer) and prints it out like it was an integer - because you told it so (`%i`), hence the output of the program.

PHP uses dynamic type definition so your variables are interpreted in the context in which they are used (unless sometimes forced to be a certain type by casting or using settype()).

I.e.: `$a = 1;` will be an `integer` but if you do another assignment like `$a += 0.5;` it will be casted into a `float` automatically.

Comment: I think everyone is trying to correct my C codes. I'm actually trying to get PHP to print the same data output just like C.

Comment: I'm still stuck figuring out what to do. Can I contact you via anything? I really need to get the PHP code worked out :(

Comment: @benjdewantara I would argue that the output of the C program as in your question is incorrect because of reasons stated in the answers. Why would you want to the PHP program to give (mathematically) incorrect result too?

Comment: Well.. It's true that the the C is wrong.. Actually, I asked the wrong question.. Can you help me with this? Why http://pastebin.com/rkdk92Cu won't generate the same output like http://pastebin.com/K8qHzexB